# How can I remove a computer from Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, connector

I have the following computers connected to my Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials:
[image]

When I try to *Remove the computer* with the tasks menu, it fails unexpectedly with the following error:
[image]

Following the provided link (https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj730365.aspx) does not give me any information on how to troubleshoot this issue.

How can I do so?

The machine is not available anymore, as I forgot to remove the instance upon reinstallation (which is now *DESKTOP-03JUF28*), so there's no chance to reconnect (except with a fresh installation, with the same naming - which I want to avoid).

Comment: Did you already try it with the `Remove-WssComputer` cmdlet in PowerShell? The Shell is always the strongest option in my opinion.

Comment: @SimonS not yet - thanks for that hint. If it works, can you expand your comment to answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: sure thing! if that command doesn't work, you could maybe try another one from this list https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205088%28v=wps.630%29.aspx

Comment: @SimonS yes, `Remove-WssComputer` worked. Thank you very much! Could you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already try it with the `Remove-WssComputer` cmdlet in PowerShell? The Shell is always the strongest option in my opinion.

Comment: Please write a complete answer - as requested by OP.

Comment: @guntbert The challenging part is to iterate through `Get-WssComputer` to select the item you want to remove with `Remove-WssComputer`. This crucial part is covered in the documentation (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205092.aspx), but you are right: for a fully fledged answer this should be included!

Comment: since the question is now answered, and my answer was actually intended to be a comment (as you can see if you read through the comments), I won't do that anymore.